# Problem get full contents of boygj.com in feed using Yahoo Pipes

Tags: pipe, feed, yahoo-pipes

I've tried many times to get full contents of `boygj.com` in feed using Yahoo Pipes

In the pipes is:

- Fetch feed `http://boygj.com/rss.xml`
- Cut content from `<div class="content">` to `<div class="service-links">`

...all those contents assigned to `item.description.content`

But the pipes always showing wrong cutting.

What happened and what is the solution?

Comment: Can we have the link to your pipe ?

Answer (score 0):

`http://boygj.com/rss.xml` is a RSS 2.0 feed, there is no `div` to cut.

Instead, use the Fetch Page module to get `http://boygj.com` and parse it with the YQL module ([sample](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A//finance.yahoo.com/q%3Fs%3Dyhoo%22%20and%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xpath%3D%27//div%5B@id%3D%22yfi_headlines%22%5D/div%5B2%5D/ul/li/a%27))