# Problem get full contents of heroturko.org in feed using Yahoo Pipes

Tags: pipe, feed, yahoo-pipes

I've tried many times to get full contents of `heroturko.org` in feed using Yahoo Pipes

In the pipes is:

- Fetch feed
  `http://www.heroturko.org/wallpapers/rss.xml`
- From feed, fetch `item.link`
- Cut content from `<div
  class="article">` to `<div
  align="center">`

...all those contents lastly assigned to `description`

This is link to the pipe:
`http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=334497bf3eaef62bfe32509e36db92ff`

But the pipes always showing nothing in the result feed description.

I've tried to make `item.link` renamed to `description` only using Rename module (Without Loop module), but also nothing showing in the description

Comment: I dont know well about yahoo pipes, but why are you using Rename module

Comment: are you the same user as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857573/problem-get-full-contents-of-boygj-com-in-feed-using-yahoo-pipes ?

Comment: Some website need this to work. This is for example:`http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=nABicbMV3hG7WsDOwTSbTQ`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like no problem in your pipe.. maybe blank in description because yahoo server failed to browse heroturko.org (heroturko.org is hosted in Czech Republic)

correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: heroturko.org is down long time but heroturko2.com is available and still working